# Remove Check Box blue border

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, border

I've created CheckBox with ios style:

```
<form>
<input id="ckbx" type="checkbox"  value="map_one">
</form>
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gady11/yzkK9/)

Ive tried to remove the ***blue border*** that created when clicked the button,
without success.

plz help me to remove it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use outline:0 this will remove the blue boarder

```
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus{
        outline:0;
    }
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yzkK9/1/)

Comment: Keep in mind that this makes it impossible to see whether the checkbox is selected by keyboard navigation using the TAB key.